# IBAction Not getting called after upgrade to (SDK 8.1 , Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im using IBAction to set action for my buttons.

The buttons are in uitableview Cell.

this is my code :

```
-(IBAction)buttonAcceptClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if ([NSProcessInfo instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:)]) {
         cell = (UITableViewCell*)btn.superview.superview;
          NSLog(@"sdk 8.1");

    } else {
         cell = (UITableViewCell*)btn.superview.superview.superview;
        NSLog(@"sdk 7.1");
    }
    NSLog(@"buttonAcceptClick");
```

2nd button is exactly like first one with different name.

now problem is everything works well in Xcode 5 and SDK 7.1 , but after i opened my project

in Xcode 6 and SDK 8.1 the program runs well on iPhone 4,5,6 simulator (sdks 7.1 and 8.1) ,

but not working on real device. and fun part is one of buttons working and not the other

one.

Comment: I would double check that the outlet is connected in the storyboard. If the reason you are checking the system version is to know how to get the cell, there is probably a better way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for respond . i will check the outlet or rebuild new one.
also how can i get the cell info in better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, there are better (more reliable) ways to get the the UITableViewCell. Here is one:

```
- (IBAction)someButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint point = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // do something with the cell...
}
```